# Visual Studio 2019 showing ESLint errors for Power Apps CLI generated TypeScript file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, eslint, powerapps

I created a Power Apps Component Framework (PCF) project using Power Apps CLI (PAC). I used following commands:

```
// initializes directory with a new PCF project  
pac pcf init  

// installs the project dependencies
npm install
```

With this basic project code, when I open the project folder in Visual Studio 2019 it shows multiple ESLint errors in index.ts (TypeScript) file. However, the same code shows no error in Visual Studio 2017.

- Both versions of VS have ESLint enabled (Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript/TypeScript -> Linting -> General -> Enable ESLint = true)
- Both VS versions are using the same global ESLint config file located in my user folder
- If I disable ESLint is VS2019, errors disappear

**My concerns are**

1. How can I resolve these ESLint errors in VS2019 while keeping ESLint enabled?
2. If I disable ESLint in VS2019, would this impact the development of the project?

Please have a look at the VS2019 snapshot, PAC generated ESLint config file and global ESLint config file contents below.

[image]

**.eslintrc.json**
project file contents

```
    {
        "env": {
            "browser": true,
            "es2021": true
        },
        "extends": [
            "standard"
        ],
        "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaVersion": 12,
            "sourceType": "module"
        },
        "plugins": [
            "@typescript-eslint"
        ],
      "rules": {
      }
    }
```

**Global ESLint configuration file**
.eslintrc file found in my user folder

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true // Allows support of JSX, but use of React plugin is required to support React semantics
    }
  },
  // @typescript-eslint/parser is specified as a command line argument
  "plugins": [
    "node",
    "promise",
    "react",
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "env": {
    "amd": true,
    "browser": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true, // This enables ES6 global variables AND ES6 syntax
    "worker": true
  },
  "rules": {
    // The below are some, but not all, of the rules from eslint:recommended https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/conf/eslint-recommended.js (all errors set to warning)
    "constructor-super": 1,
    "for-direction": 1,
    "getter-return": 1,
    "no-async-promise-executor": 1,
    "no-case-declarations": 1,
    "no-class-assign": 1,
    "no-compare-neg-zero": 1,
    "no-cond-assign": 1,
    "no-const-assign": 1,
    "no-constant-condition": 1,
    "no-control-regex": 1,
    "no-debugger": 1,
    "no-delete-var": 1,
    "no-dupe-args": 1,
    "no-dupe-class-members": 1,
    "no-dupe-keys": 1,
    "no-duplicate-case": 1,
    "no-empty": 1,
    "no-empty-character-class": 1,
    "no-empty-pattern": 1,
    "no-ex-assign": 1,
    "no-extra-boolean-cast": 1,
    "no-fallthrough": 1,
    "no-func-assign": 1,
    "no-global-assign": 1,
    "no-inner-declarations": 1,
    "no-invalid-regexp": 1,
    "no-misleading-character-class": 1,
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 1,
    "no-new-symbol": 1,
    "no-obj-calls": 1,
    "no-octal": 1,
    "no-prototype-builtins": 1,
    "no-redeclare": 1,
    "no-regex-spaces": 1,
    "no-self-assign": 1,
    "no-shadow-restricted-names": 1,
    "no-sparse-arrays": 1,
    "no-this-before-super": 1,
    "no-unexpected-multiline": 1,
    "no-unreachable": 1,
    "no-unsafe-finally": 1,
    "no-unsafe-negation": 1,
    "no-unused-labels": 1,
    "no-useless-catch": 1,
    "no-useless-escape": 1,
    "no-with": 1,
    "require-atomic-updates": 1,
    "require-yield": 1,
    "use-isnan": 1,
    "valid-typeof": 1,

    // Other rules
    "default-param-last": 1,
    "eqeqeq": 1,

    // The below are some, but not all, of the rules from eslint-plugin-react:recommended https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#recommended (all errors set to warn)
    "react/display-name": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
    "react/no-children-prop": 1,
    "react/no-danger-with-children": 1,
    "react/no-deprecated": 1,
    "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 1,
    "react/no-find-dom-node": 1,
    "react/no-is-mounted": 1,
    "react/no-render-return-value": 1,
    "react/no-string-refs": 1,
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": 1,
    "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
    "react/require-render-return": 1,

    // Some additional React rules
    "react/no-danger": 1,
    "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1
  },

  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [ "*.ts", "*.tsx" ],
      "rules": {
        // The below are all rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint:recommended https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/eslint-recommended.ts (all errors set to warn)
        "getter-return": 0, //Checked by Typescript - ts(2378)
        "no-dupe-args": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(2300)
        "no-dupe-keys": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(1117)
        "no-unreachable": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(7027)
        "valid-typeof": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(2367)
        "no-const-assign": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(2588)
        "no-new-symbol": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(2588)
        "no-this-before-super": 0, // Checked by Typescript - ts(2376)
        "no-undef": 0, // This is checked by Typescript using the option `strictNullChecks`.
        "no-dupe-class-members": 0, // This is already checked by Typescript.
        "no-redeclare": 0, // This is already checked by Typescript.

        // The below is some, but not all, of the rules from @typescript-eslint/recommended https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/recommended.json (all errors set to warn)
        "@typescript-eslint/adjacent-overload-signatures": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": 1,
        "camelcase": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/class-name-casing": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style": 1,
        "no-array-constructor": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-array-constructor": 1,
        "no-empty-function": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-new": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": 1,
        "no-unused-vars": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": 1,
        "no-use-before-define": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/prefer-namespace-keyword": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference": 1,
        "@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing": 1,
        "no-var": 1,
        "prefer-const": 1,
        "prefer-rest-params": 1,
        "prefer-spread": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My block looks like the following and things are working fine (though I don't have a global `eslint` config):

```js
extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
],
```